# MongoDB cannot multiply dates

Tags: mongodb

For a collection, I'm attempting to sort the documents by dates, but the order may vary depending on another condition. For example

```
{ _id: 1, name: 'Foo 1', eta: '2016-07-31', status: 'complete' },
{ _id: 2, name: 'Foo 2', eta: '2016-09-16', status: 'pending' },
{ _id: 3, name: 'Foo 3', eta: '2016-07-12', status: 'complete' },
{ _id: 4, name: 'Foo 4', eta: '2016-08-31', status: 'pending' }
```

(**Note**: for the sake of this question, `eta` is actually a `Date` type.)

and this should be sorted such that the `eta` is acending for `status = 'pending'` but descending otherwise.

```
{ _id: 4, name: 'Foo 4', eta: '2016-08-31', status: 'pending' },
{ _id: 2, name: 'Foo 2', eta: '2016-09-16', status: 'pending' },
{ _id: 1, name: 'Foo 1', eta: '2016-07-31', status: 'complete' },
{ _id: 3, name: 'Foo 3', eta: '2016-07-12', status: 'complete' }
```

So, I wrote an aggregation to add two extra fields :

```
statusOrder: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ '$status', 'pending' ] }, 0, 1 ] },
etaOrder: { $multiply: [ '$eta', { $cond: [ { $eq: [ '$status', 'pending' ] }, 1, -1 ] } ] }
```

But it seems that, if I can `$add` a date, I cannot multiply it. So, how can I convert the date field into a number so I can multiply it? Do I need to create, yet, another field??

---

### ** Edit **

From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/) :

> Internally, Date objects are stored as a 64 bit integer representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970), which results in a representable date range of about 290 millions years into the past and future.

So, if dates are stored as a number, how can a manipulate this value directly during an aggregation?

---

### ** Edit 2 **

There *are* some [date operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/), but none returns the whole date in milliseconds!

Comment: exactly how do you multiply a date? what is `today * 2`? `2016-08-25 * 2` becomes `4032-16-50`?

Comment: @MarcB the operator `$add` treats the `Date` object as milliseconds. I exected `$multiply` to act the same

Comment: @MarcB if you'd take the time to read the question, you'd understand that I'm using the date field as a sorting value.

Comment: date addition is conceptually simple. exactly what do you expect the result to be upon multiplication? if it's just a millisecond view, then `timestamp * 2` is easy. but what about `ts1 * ts2`? right now as I write this, my JS timestamp is `1472154681333`. what should the result be for multiplying by yesterday?

Comment: @MarcB again, if you'd care to actually read the question instead of focusing on minor details, you'd read the actual question that I'm asking, the very last statement in the question.

Comment: I understand that. But what makes you think mongo (or any other db) would know what you're thinking? they have to handle ALL cases, not just your specific positive/negative operation.

Comment: @MarcB In any SQL, you can convert a `date` type into a number, and manipulate it. So far, I haven't came across something as simple as that in MongoDB, but `$add` that says that it can add dates with numbers and wondered if the same applied to multiplications, then stated the entire situation and possible quesiton at the end. Please, read before arguing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subtract two Dates using [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/#exp._S_subtract), the result is the difference in milliseconds. So you can convert `eta` to milliseconds using:

```
{$subtract: ['$eta', new Date(0)]}
```

So you can put that together with what you have so far to make:

```
etaOrder: {$multiply: [{$subtract: ['$eta', new Date(0)]}, 
                       {$cond: [{$eq: ['$status', 'pending']}, 1, -1 ]}]}
```

But you could simplify that a bit to avoid the multiplication by just swapping the `$subtract` terms based on the `$cond`:

```
etaOrder: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$status', 'pending']}, 
                   {$subtract: ['$eta', new Date(0)]}, 
                   {$subtract: [new Date(0), '$eta']} ]}
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree with comments from @MarkB above. Multiply is non- sensical here. What is a negative date anyway? Perhaps consider having two separate dates for sorting eta date and complete date, with items that are not complete not having a value for complete date than then able to be sorted differently.